# The requested URL was not found on this server error when using codeigniter with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3, wampserver

I want to make a simple app using CodeIgniter, PHP, and MySQL which collects data using a form into MySQL database. The following are my codes - 
for the form1.php, I'm using -

```
  <body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

    <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('/form/add_user'); ?>">
       Name:<br>
       <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name"><br>
       Age: <br>
       <input class="form-control" placeholder="Age" type="number" name="age"><br>
       Gender:<br>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br><br>
       State:<br>
       <select name="state">
         <option value="maharashtra">Maharashtra</option>
         <option value="west bengal">West Bengal</option>
         <option value="kerela">Kerela</option>
         <option value="bihar">Bihar</option>
       </select><br>
       <br>    
       <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" >
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

For the controller -

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper('url');
      $this->load->model('user_model');
}

public function index()
{
$this->load->view("form1.php");
}

public function add_user(){

    $user=array(
    'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
    'age'=>$this->input->post('age'),
    'gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
    'state'=>$this->input->post('state')
      );
      print_r($user);


    $this->user_model->add_user($user);
    redirect ('form');
```

And the user model looks like -

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_model{

public function add_user($user){
  $this->db->insert('user', $user);
}

}
?>
```

Now I get my form when I put http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/ in the browser.
I am using `WAMP` server and the name of my app is samplesurvey.
But when I submit, I get the error:

> The requested URL /samplesurvey/form/add_user was not found on this
>   server.

I have edited the `.htaccess` file and the Apache module as in other answers but it is not working.

Comment: use `site_url` function instead of `base_url` , `<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('form/add_user'); ?>">` and make sure in `config.php` file `base_url` set to `http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey`

Comment: create a virtual host, easy on wamp to change the entry of your site form ` http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/ ` to ` http:// samplesurvey/ `, it's not a good practice to keep the local address entry 127.0.0.1 and it will solve your probleme

Comment: @jagad89 tried that but not working

Comment: @VipulModak inspect element in the browser and see the action URL of form, what is it?

Comment: action="http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/form/add_user" @jagad89

Comment: It should be `action="http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/form/add_user"` make sure in your `config.php` set to `http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey`

Comment: @jagad89 $config['base_url'] = "http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/"; this is my config i dont know why the http part is not showing

Comment: add `http` like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/'`

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey/';` this is my config.php setting of base url

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: @jagad89 it is not working.

Comment: update your question with content of `form1.php` file.

Comment: follow these 3 step carefully,
1. in form change `<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('form/add_user'); ?>">`
2. remove `.htaccess` file temporary from root.
3. update `config.php` file with below `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey'; $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot! can you tell me what was my mistake?

Comment: Now just put back the `.htaccess` file, if after putting back `.htaccess` the solution stop working that means something wrong with `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @VipulModak If the issue has been solved, you should consider accepting the answer so it helps others in future who will face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good practice to use `site_url` instead of `base_url` while defining action URL of a form.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('form/add_user'); ?>">
```

wrong `.htaccess` can be the issue, so temporarily remove the `.htaccess` file.

Make sure in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/samplesurvey'; 
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

It should work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly thanks. There was some problem with `.htaccess` file. I changed the code in it and it works perfectly now.